# Kubernetes: "Liveness probe failed: rm: cannot remove '/tmp/healthy': No such file or directory"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

After installing the helm charts of an application, I am getting the following error:

```
Liveness probe failed: rm: cannot remove '/tmp/healthy': No such file or directory
```

The command to remove is inside the pod definition wihtin the helm charts

The pod is created but the containers keeps on failing and displays the above error. But since the file doesn't exist, how can I create the file first or at least sort out the error ?

Comment: Can you give a hint which helm chart this is? To me, this looks like a problem with the particular chart.

Comment: The apparent intent is that the flag file /tmp/healthy should no longer exist. The code is buggy in that it fails when it tries to make not-existing something that is already not-existing. The fix is probably to use 'rm -f'.

Comment: @pvorb : Please check the update. Sadly I can't share the full chart but I updated the  question with `yaml-dictionary` where the file should be removed. There is no `cat` or `touch` command

Comment: Hi @iggy, please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Done, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apparent intent is that the flag file /tmp/healthy should no longer exist.

The code is buggy in that it fails when it tries to make not-existing something that is already not-existing.

The fix is probably to use 'rm -f'.

---

For background, the 'liveness probe' is a periodic check by kubernetes on the health or otherwise of a pod.  There are a number of forms the check can take; a simple one is the presence or absence of a specified file.